# Creating a custom terms and conditions middleware using django

Tags: django

I am trying to  create a custom middleware that checks for a term and conditions update. I have a model field called User which has a Boolean field. I added my middleware file under MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. For the last part of the task I have started writing my middeware.py file:

```
@login_required
class DisplayConditions(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
```

After that I have the following ideas: Send a query to the database and get the user info. From there I can check if the field is True or False. Please can anyone help with that part. I am not asking for code. It would be nice if someone provides some useful or some thoughts. Sorry for the newbie question, it is my first big project using django

Answer (score 0):

You have a user in `request` object, so you can check:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

...
    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.your_flag:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('url_to_conditions_page')
```